# How do we correctly format a LinkedIn post request for a field selector (one containing colons and parentheses)?

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am successfully using the LinkedIn People Profile API to access for a user, and after the user grants permission, and after exchanging the authentication code for a 60 day access token I can make POST requests and return various profile data.

I'm using PHP based on the sample code at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples.

Until now, all my requests have worked. For example, this one works:

```
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,num-connections,headline,industry,specialties,summary,public-profile-url,email-address,interests,publications,languages,skills,three-current-positions,phone-numbers,main-address,twitter-accounts,primary-twitter-account,educations,num-recommenders)');
```

The fetch function (from the sample code mentioned above) builds the POST request, makes the request and returns the $user object filled with all the data.

However, if I add the following two fields, which are defined as field selectors:

```
location:(name),location:(country:(code))
```

so the above statement becomes:

```
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,location:(name),location:(country:(code)),num-connections,headline,industry,specialties,summary,public-profile-url,email-address,interests,publications,languages,skills,three-current-positions,phone-numbers,main-address,twitter-accounts,primary-twitter-account,educations,num-recommenders)');
```

nothing at all is returned from fetch.

To test, in the fetch function, immediately after the:

```
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

statement I added the statement:

```
print 'response: ' . print_r($response, true);
```

and in the returned page it just shows "response: " with an empty value - not even an error message.

But if I remove the two field selector fields the request works fine and all the information is returned.

I'm guessing I need to specify those two fields in some different format, but I can't figure out from the docs and examples what that format might be, so I'm hoping somebody here can give me a hint.

I'm also curious why no error is returned - just a blank value. An error message would be useful for debugging.

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-fields should be aggregated, e.g.:

```
location:(name,country:(code))
```

There should be only one occurrence of `location` in your query.

If in doubt check your query in [LinkedIn REST-console](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console), for your query I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
  <status>400</status>
  <timestamp>1422276799156</timestamp>
  <request-id>XMQPA0BXDC</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>Duplicate field {location} in inline filter {(first-name,last-name,location:(name),location:(country:(code)),num-connections,headline,industry,specialties,summary,public-profile-url,email-address,interests,publications,languages,skills,three-current-positions,phone-numbers,main-address,twitter-accounts,primary-twitter-account,educations,num-recommenders))}</message>
</error>
```

which clearly indicates problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion and report back. However, the LinkedIn REST-console does not work for me on my Mac running Yosemite in Firefox, Chrome or Safari. The page reports that I don't have cookies enabled, even though I do. So I don't see how I can use that useful-looking testing tool. Anyway, I will report back after testing. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I confirmed that the problem was just not consolidating the location, as you stated, and the call is working fine now. I appreciate the help!